# how to send props with props component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Now, I'm trying send props to component from props, but I can't. What should I do?

Can someone tell me how to props component to props component
(Focus header.jsx file I need to send the value in props of  but I can't

Thank you.

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Route component={App}/>
        </Provider>
    </HashRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

app.jsx

```
render() {
    const { location, lang } = this.props
    return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <IntlProvider key={lang} locale={lang} messages={messages[lang]}>
        <Layout>
                <Switch>
                    <GuestRoute location={location} path='/' component={Welcome} exact/>
                    <GuestRoute location={location} path='/reset/:token' component={ForgotPassword} exact/>
                    <UserRoute location={location} path='/profile' component={Info} exact/>
                    <UserRoute location={location} path='/reset' component={ResetPassword} exact/>
                    <UserRoute location={location} path='/myrestaurant' component={MyRestaurant} exact/>
                    <UserRoute location={location} path='/myrestaurant/:resname' component={MyRestaurant} exact/>
                </Switch>
        </Layout>
        </IntlProvider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

layout.jsx

```
class InfoPage extends Component {
    render() {
        const { isAuthenticated } = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                { 
                    isAuthenticated 
                        ?
                        <HeaderAuth 
                            component={this.props.children}
                        />
                        :
                    <HeaderNAuth />
                }
                { !isAuthenticated && this.props.children }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

header.jsx

```
    render() {
        const { classes, locale, theme, logout } = this.props

        return(
            <div className={classes.root}>

                    {
                        this.props.component <-------------- HERE I NEED PROPS VALUE TO THIS COMPONENT ----------------> // what should i do
                    }

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: In you link of `codesandbox` the prop `hello props` is successfully sent to the     `<SomeInnerComponent />`. You want to send any `component` in `props`?

Comment: @Maheer Ali thank you for reply, that link of codesandbox do not care i'm wrong, but i want you focus header.jsx file i need to send value in props like <this.prop.component value="fromparent /> but i can't

Comment: Best if you want to send the the children of parent component to his his child so here I gave example in the answer

Comment: Can you show where you are using `<InfoPage />`?

Comment: @dabishan InfoPage is Layout Component it call in app.jsx

Comment: I dont know if this is what you may need, but have you looked into [Higher Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) ? They let you create component that you can pass component as prop.

Comment: thank you for all reply , now i using redux it worked

Answer (score 1):

Here you can pass whole component in HeaderAuth.

```
class InfoPage extends Component {
    render() {
        const { isAuthenticated } = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                { 
                    isAuthenticated 
                        ?
                        <HeaderAuth newValue={'hello world'}> 
                          {this.props.children}
                        <HeaderAuth/>
                        :
                    <HeaderNAuth />
                }
                { !isAuthenticated && this.props.children }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Now, Inside HeaderAuth, you can access that component inside this.props.children.

```
render() {
        const { classes, locale, theme, logout, newValue } = this.props

        return(
            <div className={classes.root}>
                {newValue}
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but i want to send value in props of {this.props.children} how ? like <this.props.children value="fromparent" />

Comment: @BestBest I've updated my answer. Instead of doing < this.props.children value='fromparent'/> . You can pass from the parent component

Comment: nono i don't want to use in HeaderAuth.jsx but i want to use in component of this.props.children, i want to send value to children component again send value from HeaderAuth again

Comment: @BestBest I dont think we can pass it that way. If you want to pass the props then you have to do it from parent component itself. Here this.props.children is not a component, its a JSX only.

Comment: you have some idea of this or no ? if you can tell me please , i trying alway but can't

Answer (score 0):

**Parent**

```
class Parent extends Component {
    render() { 
        return ( <div><Child component={this.props.children}/></div> );
    }
}
```

**Child To which parent will pass his chilren**

```
class Child extends Component{
    render(){
        return(<div>{this.props.component}I am a child which revieve component in props</div>)
    }
}
```

**Parent Component is rendered with a div as his child**

```
ReactDOM.render(<Parent>
    <div style={{color:"red"}}>I am the comppent passed as from parent to Child</div>
    </Parent>, document.getElementById("root"));
```